# Where's the documentation for using Relationships with Grid fields?

Tags: relationships, grid

I'm trying to do something like:

> {grid_fields}
>
> {grid_fields:relationship}{title}{/grid_fields:relationship}
>
> {/grid_fields}

But I don't seem to be able to pull data out of the related entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Been searching for a similar solution and your answer was extremely helpful James Muspratt. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm using EE v2.7.0 and the syntax actually appears to be:

```
{grid_fields}
     {grid_fields:relationship}{grid_fields:relationship:title}{/grid_fields:relationship}
{/grid_fields}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try...

```
{grid_fields}
     {grid_fields:relationship}{relationship:title}{/grid_fields:relationship}
{/grid_fields}
```

As of 2.6 the relationship field should be prepended with the relationship field name so that advanced relationships can work together with each other. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#child-entries-displaying-the-stores-and-their-menus