# How do I include a Relationship field inside a Grid?

Tags: relationships, grid

In an EE 3 site I have a Grid field with four Grid fields, one of which is a relationship field. Content from the first three Grid Fields display properly, the relationship field does not display at all.

Here is my code:

```
  {content}
    <div class="hub-box col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
      <img src="{content:thumbnail}" alt="{content:title}" />
      <h3>{content:title}</h3>
        <p>{content:summary}</p>
        <p>{content:links_to}{content:links_to:title}{/content:links_to}</p>
    </div>  
   {/content}
```

In the output. The thumbnail, title and summary all display fine, but the relationship field content is blank.

I have confirmed that the relationship field in the grid has content selected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall if you're inside a relationship inside a matrix you revert to standard tags, so this

```
<p>{content:links_to}{content:links_to:title}{/content:links_to}</p>
```

Changed to this

```
<p>{content:links_to}{links_to:title}{/content:links_to}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{content:links_to}{title}{/content:links_to}</p>
```

**UPDATE**
Check this [answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/14321/166) out.

Comment: I tried both of the options and nothing displays for either one. I am still open to suggestions.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to another answer :)